# Using Maven Password encryption with flyway maven plugin

Tags: maven, password-encryption, flyway

I'm using flyway and its maven plugin for database migration and my database credentials are stored in plain text format in the server section of .m2/settings.xml.

I'd like to avoid this and to encrypt them using the Maven encryption mechanism as described in the [Maven password encryption mini guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html). Unfortunately I always get logon denied errors using the encrypted password in settings.xml. So it seems that the flyway maven plugin is not decrypting the passwort.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet. Please file a bug in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/list).

**Update:** I had some time on my train ride today. Implemented.

Comment: Wow, that are fantastic news! Thanks a lot, Axel! :-)
Can you already tell in which version of flyway the changes will be integrated?

Comment: How about this now?

Comment: looking for any documentation/exmaples on this and cannot seem to find any?